# How to change master view width in SwiftUI split view on iPad

Tags: swiftui

Is it possible to increase the default width of the master view in SwiftUI split view implemented with NavigationView on iPad?

```
NavigationView {
   masterView
   detailView
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the default width of the master view you may install [SwiftUI-Introspect](https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect) and add this to your NavigationView:

```
.introspectNavigationController { navigationController in
    navigationController.splitViewController?.preferredPrimaryColumnWidthFraction = 1
    navigationController.splitViewController?.maximumPrimaryColumnWidth = *preferred width*
}
```